# $f: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ where $\overline{f(\mathbb{R})}\neq f(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: general-topology

I'm having trouble coming up with a (continuous) function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ where the closure of the range (w.r.t. the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$) is not the same as the range. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: A half step to understand the phenomenon is to take $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ first. For example, $f(x)=\arctan x$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a continuous surjection $ g: \mathbb R \to (0,1)$ and compose it with the inclusion of $(0,1)$ to the $x$-axis in $\mathbb R^2$.

Or something like

$$ f(x) = \frac{x^2}{x^2 +1} (\cos x, \sin x), $$

the closure will also contains the unit circle (which is not in the image).

You only require that the image is not closed, so there are a lot of possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

Another simple example: $f(t)=(e^t, 0)$. Is not relevant that the codomain is in higher dimensions.

Comment: @A.S., range$\ne$graph.